# Files prefixed with exclamation points and numbers showing up in Pycharm project

Tags: macos, pycharm

I'm working on a project in Pycharm, and lately I've noticed an odd thing: empty files are being created that mirror the names of already existing files, but prefixed with exclamation points and numbers. They're not even necessarily files I'm actively doing anything with in the project.

For example, as I'm on a Mac, each of my directories has a `.DS_Store` file, and now, a couple of the directories also have something like `.!19564!.DS_Store`. Or where I had `deployment_file.zip` I now also have `.!18274!deployment_file.zip`. I've never been able to pinpoint the exact moment one of these files is created (as they don't occur all the time and I haven't been watching for them), so I couldn't say what is causing it.

It doesn't seem like anything I should be concerned about; it's just an unknown I would like to know. Does anybody have any idea what this is?